# return plain text in ajax, puntuation issues

Tags: html, ajax, non-ascii-characters

I have to return a plain text got from a file from server and show in my webpage.

I am getting the file fine with ajax but I have problems with accents because it is in spanish and I have special characters like á, é, í...

Instead of that, I am getting squares with interrogation mark inside.

txt file has the correct symbol and I see it fine inside of it.

This is how I am getting and showing the file:

```
$.when(

   $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: urlServer+"openDocument.php",
                 contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "text",
                 success: function(response) {
                     respuesta = response;
                 },

                 error: function(xhr, status, message) { alert("Status: " + status + "\nsaveDocument: " + message); }
                 })


                 ).then(function(){
                     //console.log(respuesta);
                    document.getElementById("divInfo").innerHTML = respuesta;
                 }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataType:
```

The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

```
contentType:
```

When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"`, which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). The `W3C XMLHttpRequest` specification dictates that the charset is always `UTF-8;` specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding.

Your `dataType` is wrong. The default is: Intelligent Guess, other available types are (`xml, json, script, or html`). It should be `html` in your case.
Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thanks but I am still getting the same problem. I changed to html and deleted contentType due to nothing is sent to the server.